# Hilbert's basis theorem?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, noetherian

Can someone tell me if this is what we call "Hilbert's basis theorem"?

> *Let $R$ be a noetherian ring. Then $R[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ is also a noetherian ring.*

Thanks in advance.

PD. Is there any illustrative example out there where it is used? My teacher just wrote it in the whiteboard, but never told us about its potential and I'm pretty interested in it.

Comment: Yes, this is Hilbert's Basis Theorem. It was originally used to prove that the ring of invariants is finitely generated, solving [Gordan's Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Hilbert#Hilbert_solves_Gordan's_Problem), one of his earliest and more famous results, which "put him on the map", as it were. It also is used in Algebraic Geometry to show that every algebraic set can be described as the set of common zeroes of finitely many polynomials.

Comment: This theorem shows that there are "many" Noetherian rings. For example, one simple corollary is that any finitely generated algebra over a Noetherian ring (in particular, over a field) is Noetherian. As mentioned in the comment above, Hilbert's original motivation was to prove a result in invariant theory: if $A$ is a finitely generated (commutative, unital) algebra over a field $F$ and $G$ is a finite group of automorphisms of $A$, then the subalgebra $A^G=\{a\in A: g(a)=a \ \forall g\in G\}$ is also finitely generated. That result has really surprised the mathematicians of that time.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that the theorem had that amount of repercussions. Thanks!